# MySQL: Dates as column headers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to develop a new reporting module for a resource management tool (PHP+Mysql).

I am trying to extract data in the following format from mysql:

[image: Output Example]
I have a table that consists of date and location of multiple people(i.e Office, Home or Client).

Sample Data as in DB.

[image: Data as in plotting table]

here date_plotted means the date at which the user is engaged and plotting_date represents when this particular entry was made in the system(the date). So User was plotted to be in office on 30th Oct and the same entry was made on 30th Oct.

[Data as in resource table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHcPW.png)

The resource table represents the user table.

Any suggestions on how to do the same in mysql?

These are the primary tables which needs to be used. 
The above table id done in excel for now to represent the outcome. 
I'm new to SQL so haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: This needs some sample data, and something that shows what you've tried in SQL. Also is this coming straight out of MySQL or is it potentially formatted with PHP or some other language?

Comment: Updated. I dont have any idea how to do that so haven't tried anything.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities here (opinionated answers); so I don't think you'll likely get one on this site until you better define the parameters of the system you're on and what you're doing with it. Where do the dates come from in the query, what's the difference between `date_plotted` and `plotting_date`, lots of guesswork on the part of anyone answering.

Comment: hello did you solve your issue? if so can you please help me I too have to develop same

Comment: hello did you solve your issue? if so can you please help me I too have to develop same

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for Windows that might simplify this operation. It's made by MySQL and called [MySQL for Excel.](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) In theory it should allow you to structure and make changes to MySQL databases as well as perform queries that result in spreadsheets.

Without knowing more about your data, for example being supplied an actual csv file to work with, and the parameters of the actual pull, whether it's fix dates always or if this is a dynamic pull based on a range this question could result in 100 different implementations that visually return similar results, but have massively different requirements overhead-wise in implementation.